# registerScriptFile in Yii loading wrong jquery in just one action/file

Tags: php, yii

bit of a yii newb here, though I have lots of experience with PHP and other programming languages and frameworks.

I have a controller file (loaded out of protected/modules/portal/controllers) and all the actions in it use (protected/views/layouts/main.php) to render

in that layout file theres this

```
    <?php

Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCssFile('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600');
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCssFile($baseUrl . '/css/style.css');
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCssFile($baseUrl . '/css/normalize.css');
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCssFile($baseUrl . '/css/select2.css');

Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCssFile($baseUrl . '/css/owl.carousel.css');
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCssFile($baseUrl . '/css/owl.theme.css');
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScriptFile($baseUrl . '/js/jquery.min.js');
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScriptFile($baseUrl . '/js/scroll-startstop.events.jquery.js');
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScriptFile($baseUrl . '/js/jquery-migrate-1.2.0.js');
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScriptFile($baseUrl . '/js/jquery.velocity.min.js');
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScriptFile($baseUrl . '/js/owl.carousel.min.js');
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScriptFile($baseUrl . '/js/device.min.js');
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScriptFile($baseUrl . '/js/fastclick.js');
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScriptFile($baseUrl . '/js/select2.js');
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScriptFile($baseUrl . '/js/script.js');
?>
```

In protected/config/main.php theres this

```
'clientScript' => array(
                        'scriptMap' => array(
                            'jquery.js' => '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js',
                            'jquery-ui.js' => '//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js',
                            'jquery.min.js' => '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js',
                            'jquery-ui.min.js' => '//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js',
                        ),
```

In most of the actions inside of the controller (using that layout template), the jquery file is loaded from googleapi as expected, but there is one particular action (using that same layout) where this doesn't happen. For some reason, it loads a local copy of jquery that sits in framework/web/js/source/jquery.js (or the jquery.min.js version), and bundles it together into an assets file along with all the other js.

I can't for the life of me figure out why this is happening. Of course I can just upload the version of jquery I want into that location and move on with my life, but I wondered if anyone had any ideas why this was happening.

Using yii 1.1.10. Don't yell at me please :\

Comment: May be you need to remove this string `Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScriptFile($baseUrl . '/js/jquery.min.js');` ?

Comment: Or to register yii from scriptMap use `Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCoreScript('jquery');`

Comment: Hope it helps http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/800/how-to-register-scripts-and-css/

Comment: @SiZE Tried both of those yesterday in an 8 hour marathon trying to debug this thing. none of them worked. Why would I want to remove the jquery.min.js line though?

Comment: Libraries like CGridView using `Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCoreScript('jquery')` to register jQuery which location takes from scriptMap and also you manualy register another library `jquery.min.js`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after spending an inordinate amount of time tracking this down, I figured out the problem.

That particular page was loading a widget

```
$this->widget('comments.widgets.ECommentsListWidget ...);
```

and inside of that widget was this

```
$cs = Yii::app()->getClientScript();
$cs->scriptMap = array(
    'jquery.min.js' => false,
);
```

Hopefully you're not pointing and laughing at me right now, but basically this was overriding my scriptmap configuration specifically so that the widget would load with the jquery from the framework location I specified above. Once I commented that out, it loaded the version of jquery I had specified, and as an added bonus the jquery.ui version I wanted (for weeks I hadn't understood why it was loading the wrong version of that even though it was loading the right jquery version from googleapi on other pages).

It makes sense because you definitely want to include a known version of jquery that works with your js library (the widget would include a comment.js file in the concatenated assets file), but it feels a bit too hidden/obscure for my liking.

Either way. I'm glad I found it, hope it helps someone else. Thanks for the suggestions @SiZE